# Segmentation fault while populating vectors using pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a class of the following form:

```
class myClass{
    vector<pair<uint64_t,uint64_t> > myvarClass;
};


main(){
    vector<myClass> myVec;
    myVec.resize(8);
    myClass obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5,obj6,obj7,obj8;
    myVec.push_back(obj1);myVec.push_back(obj2);myVec.push_back(obj3);
    myVec.push_back(obj4);myVec.push_back(obj5);myVec.push_back(obj6);
    myVec.push_back(obj7);myVec.push_back(obj8);
    myClass* obj1Ptr=&myVec[0]; myClass* obj2Ptr=&myVec[1];
    myClass* obj3Ptr=&myVec[2]; myClass* obj4Ptr=&myVec[3];
    myClass* obj5Ptr=&myVec[4]; myClass* obj6Ptr=&myVec[5];
    myClass* obj7Ptr=&myVec[6]; myClass* obj8Ptr=&myVec[7];
    obj1Ptr->myvarClass.push_back(make_pair(938474,475575));
    //populate myvarClass using obj1Ptr such that the size of myvar for each class object is 4,00,000. I am not showing population of 4,00,000 myvarClass objects for brevity
    //populate myvarClass using obj2Ptr such that the size of myvar for each class object is 4,00,000.  I am not showing population of 4,00,000 myvarClass objects for brevity
    //populate myvarClass using obj3Ptr such that the size of myvar for each class object is 4,00,000.  I am not showing population of 4,00,000 myvarClass objects for brevity
    //populate myvarClass using obj4Ptr such that the size of myvar for each class object is 4,00,000. I am not showing population of 4,00,000 myvarClass objects for brevity
    //populate myvarClass using obj5Ptr such that the size of myvar for each class object is 4,00,000. I am not showing population of 4,00,000 myvarClass objects for brevity
    //populate myvarClass using obj6Ptr such that the size of myvar for each class object is 4,00,000. I am not showing population of 4,00,000 myvarClass objects for brevity
    //populate myvarClass using obj7Ptr such that the size of myvar for each class object is 4,00,000. I am not showing population of 4,00,000 myvarClass objects for brevity
    //populate myvarClass using obj8Ptr such that the size of myvar for each class object is 4,00,000. I am not showing population of 4,00,000 myvarClass objects for brevity
}
```

When I populate myvarClass using objPtr's I end up getting segmentation fault at arbitary locations. Is there any plausible cause of the same.

Comment: @dyp Thanks for pointing..that was a typo..i have corrected that

Comment: @MohitJain I am trying to populate a vector of myClass

Comment: @marom has got the problem right

Comment: @MikeMB Yes I have corrected it

Comment: This is so far removed from your real code that it is not possible to say what your real code is doing. You need to actually post real code. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post code.

Comment: You're aware that your vector has 13 elements and that the pointer that corresponds to (the copy of) `obj1` is `&myVec[5]`?  (Unless you use the `objX`es later, you could remove the `resize` and the `push_back`s and say `vector<myClass> myVec(13);`)

Comment: With your edit, you are resizing the vector to 8, thereby adding 8 default-constructed `myClass`es, then you add *another* 8. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you sure it's a segfault and not abnormal termination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After:

```
myClass obj1;
```

then `obj1` contains an uninitialized pointer. So the code:

```
myVec.push_back(obj1)
```

copies an uninitialized variable by value, which causes undefined behaviour. The same problem occurs in many places in your code.

Reading between the lines, it seems that you might give values to `myPointer` in the code you didn't show, leading to further problems. However nobody can debug code you didn't show.

Comment: I removed the uninitialized pointer from my code, still my code is giving me segmentation fault. I think resizing of myvarClass could be the potential cause of segmentation fault. What do you think? As myvarClass gets resized to 4,00,000

Comment: @StegVerner there's no segfault in the code you posted. It must be in the code you didn't post.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that as you insert pointers takes from myVec it may happen that myVec gets resized, and any pointers to its content invalidated. Hence your segfaults.

The STL when building a vector reserves a predefined number of slots. If the number of elements you insert exceeds this value then it will reserve a bigger number of slots (usually just double them) and copy the content of the old slots into the new, then release the old slots. This means that pointers to old slots get invalid. You can force the number of slots reserved in the first place (there is a constructor dedicated for that), and overcome this problem, but generally is considered bad practice relying on pointers obtained in this way. Used this way std::vector has no advantage over an array

Comment: I think you are correct. Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: If you need to store handles (can be pointers, but iterators are even better) to element of your container, then you should consider using a linked list instead of a vector.

Comment: Actually I  don't see myVec being resized after the first pointer has been taken.

Answer (score -3):

your myVec size is 5 and you push 8 elements into it. That may cause fault

Comment: That's not an issue, `std::vector` will resize itself.

Comment: `push_back` pushes a new element onto the end. The vector will have 13 elements after the pushing is done